# Unexpected behavior on 1..N relationship Mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I have 1...N relationship setup in Mongoid

```
class Student < User
  include Mongoid::Document
   ... 
  has_many :courses

class Course
  include Mongoid::Document
  belongs_to :student
```

I have 2 students

```
student1 = Student.create!(...)
student2 = Student.create!(...)


course1 = Course.create!(name: "Course 1")
course2 = Course.create!(name: "Course 2")
course3 = Course.create!(name: "Course 3")

student1.courses = [course1,course2]
student1.save!

student2.courses = [course2,course3]
student2.save!
```

Ideally what I want in mongodb

```
Student{
 coures:[CourseId,CourseId,CourseId]
}
```

What I got not ideal on two fronts

a) The relationship is saved in Coures ( I know this is as per mongoid documentation wondering if I can flip this?)

b) Course is only saving a single student id instead of a collection. So I lose data \

e.g. in mongo

```
Courses
{
"_id" : ObjectId("51f607bdb5b6057c92000005"),
"name" : "Course 1",
"student_id" : ObjectId("51f607bdb5b6057c92000002"),
}
{
"_id" : ObjectId("51f607bdb5b6057c92000006"),
"name" : "Course 2",
"student_id" : ObjectId("51f607bdb5b6057c92000003"),
}
{
"name" : "Course 3",
"student_id" : ObjectId("51f607bdb5b6057c92000003"),
}
```

I understand the http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/relations.html#has_many
shows this is correct.

But it's not what I expected. Is there some relationship for what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

Worked it out for anyone who wanted to know

added

```
class Student
  has_and_belongs_to_many :courses, inverse_of: nil
```

Also removed `belongs_to :student` from `Course`